# WinSCP: How do you add a PowerShell variable to a WinSCP PowerShell script?

Tags: powershell, winscp

I'm trying to build log path and lcd variables in my WinSCP script and I don't know the proper syntax to make it work.

How can I put the variables into the script correctly?  This is an example of what I'm trying to do.

```
$logPath = "c:\LogPath"
$lcdPath = "c:\lcdPath"

& "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com" `  
  /log = $logPath /ini=nul `
  /command `
    "open ftpSite -hostkey=`"`"hostKey`"`" -rawsettings FSProtocol=2" `
    "cd ftpFilePath" `
    $lcdPath `
    "get * -filemask=*>=1D" `
    "exit"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax for using variables is correct. It's your [WinSCP command-line syntax](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline) that is wrong.

1. There should be no spaces around switch values. And the values should better be quoted, in case they contain spaces:

   ```
   /log="$logPath"
   ```
2. The [`/log`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline#logging) takes path to a file, not path to a directory:

   ```
   $logPath = "c:\LogPath\WinSCP.log"
   ```
3. You are missing the actual [`lcd` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_lcd):

   ```
   "lcd $lcdPath" `
   ```
4. The only PowerShell issue I see in your code is that the backtick that is meant to escape a line end, has to be the last character on the line. While you have spaces after the backtick in the `WinSCP.com` line:

   ```
   & "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com" `#no spaces here
   ```